# jQuery event on dropdown and file upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown box that I need to have selected before or after a file is chosen for upload. The upload button is disabled at the start but both of these 2 need to be filled in order to enable this button.

```
$('#DropDown, input:file').on('change', function () {
    $('#uploadButton').prop('disabled', !$(this).val());
}).trigger('change');
```

This doesn't work as expected. This enables the button if just one of the elements is changed. How can I make it so they're both required?

Comment: Can we see the html also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#DropDown, input:file').on('change', function () {
   $('#uploadButton').prop('disabled', !$('#DropDown').val() || !$('input:file').val());
}).trigger('change');
```

In response to the requirement of an explanation to this answer:

Originally you were only checking the value of whichever dropdown box you were changing at the time- `$(this).val()`. So, it needed check the values of both each time you toggled either `#DropDown` or `input:file` to work correctly.

Comment: Answers which explain code are generally upvoted more often than those which simply show code... See [answer].